# Wiring of USB 2.0 hub using a USB-C connector

Tags: usb, usb-hub, usb-c

I have a [USB 2.0 hub with 7 ports and an external power supply](http://www.trust.com/en/product/15140-pyramid-7-port-usb-2-0-hub). I wanted to replace the USB 2.0 connector with [a USB type-C connector](http://www.cablecc.com/diy-24pin-usb-31-type-c-usbc-male-plug-connector-smt-type-with-35mm-sr-and-housing-cover-p-3659.html).

That connector has the following documentation:
[image: Front of USB type-C connector PCB]
[image: Back of USB type-C connector PCB]

I found the following wiring:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Type-C#Cable_wiring

I cut off the old connector and soldered the USB connector on. I hooked up A6 with the green wire, A7 with the white wire, GND with the black wire and Vbus with the red wire. Then I connected the hub with my laptop (15" Late 2016 MacBook Pro).

The laptop didn't see the hub. Why not?

Comment: Because you wired it wrong or misunderstand the compatibility issues. Instead of mucking around with a kludge like you are trying to make why not just get a proper hub. They can be acquired low cost!! This one even has power switches for each down wind port!! https://www.amazon.com/TONSUM-Ultra-Mini-Splitter-Windows-Macbook/dp/B01CNXRZU4/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1480790942&sr=8-5&keywords=USB+7+port+hub+type+C

Comment: I have already bought one. It's not about money, it's about trying to learn something.

Comment: Wikipedia is not the best (complete) source of technical information. Take a look at Type-C original specifications, found in big zip folder http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb_31_113016.zip , It is 220 pages, and, as usual, written too structurally, and hard to digest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computer does not see your device/hub because the CC1 (communication channel) pin A5 is not wired (or wired incorrectly). For the cable to be recognized as a device/hub, the CC1 pin must be pulled down with 5.1k resistor. Your connector even might have a placeholder for this resistor. Just make sure the CC1 is not pulled high to VCC, this will make the plug as "host", and your computer will switch into device mode (if it supports it).

This is the standard and fully legal captive cable configuration, see Section 3.4.3 and Table 3-11 of USB Type-C specifications.

Comment: Aha! That might be it. In the second image, to the right of GND, there's two pads that make a nice placeholder for such a resistor. And one of the pads does seem to connect to the 5th pin. Thanks, will see if a buddy has an SMD 5.1K resistor. On good faith, accepting answer.